# How can I sync Facebook contacts on a Droid X?

Tags: contacts, sync, facebook, motorola-droid-x

I used to have an original Droid and now I have a Droid X. My original Droid had an option on Facebook to sync with contacts, but with my Droid X and the new Facebook app I do not see that option. I just want the contact pictures to sync. Is there anyway to do this on the Droid X?

Answer (score 1):

This should be available. Check to see if you have Facebook selected by choosing **Accounts** from the menu in your **Address Book**.